# Getting many Objects by JSON - JAXRS

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I'm doing a RESTful JSON WS.

I need to recieve as a JSON (by POST) with many Objects.(
e.g`{"name":"carol", "age":"18"},{"name":"carlos", "age":"19"}`)

How can I put this `Array` of `Objects` into my java code?

PS: I hava a Class called `Person` which have the attributes `name` and `age`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[{"name":"carol", "age":"18"},{"name":"carlos", "age":"19"}]

You have to put array bracket at both end. I hope it works for you.

Comment: I do not want to return in many Objects as JSON, I want to recieve it BY POST(read again the question @Jugal

Comment: Mostly I generate JSON from GET method and use the same JSON to pass to Post method. Actually if JSON is much bigger then it's tough to validate.